# Character to Double && Reading from file problems for RPN Calculator implementation

Tags: c++

I asked a question previously but I've been bumping into a couple of problems along the way still. I am currently reading from a text file that contains a series of numbers, some with white space in between. This is for an RPN calculator implementation that I am doing. What I am currently having trouble with is reading whether the character that is being read is a digit or not. I am using isdigit, which I know doesn't work for a string type, hence the placement of the character c. But when I try to translate this character into a double (since my vector stack is for doubles only), I cannot just do one character at a time.

How can I edit my implementation for it to do so?

```
string line;
char c;

while (!infile.eof()){
    line = infile.get();
    c = line[0];

    if (!isdigit(c)){
        //this item is a digit
        rpn_stack.push_back(atof(line.c_str()));
    }
}
```

I appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Don't you mean `if(isdigit(c))`? Also a minimal example with inputs and expected outputs would help us understand what you're asking.

Comment: wow. that was a complete oversight! haha thanks @user3288829

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't changed the EOF detection.

Try this:

```
std::string text_from_user;
int  number_from_user;
while (getline(infile, text_from_user)
{
    // The text is now in text_from_user.
    // Now to parse the text
    std::string::size_type position = 0;
    number_from_user = 0;

    // Get length of string, as the limit in the loop.
    const std::string::size_type length = text_from_user.length();
    bool building_number = false;
    // Let's look at each character individually
    for (position = 0; position < length; ++position)
    {
         // Although there are many methods for this, this
         // method illustrates the fundamental principles.

         // Extract the character from the string.
         const char c = text_from_user[position];

         // Dispatch according to the kind of character:
         if (std::isdigit(c))
         {
             // Build an integer
             number_from_user *= 10;  // Left shift the number by decimal digit.
             number_from_user += c - '0'; // Convert from text to internal representation.

             // Process the next character:
             continue;
         }
         switch (c)
         {
             case '*':
             case '/':
             case '+':
             case '-':
                 Process_Operator(c);
                 continue;
             case '(':
             case ')':
                 Process_Grouping(c);
                 continue;
         }
    }
}
```

The above program demonstrates building of an integer.  And recognizing (dispatching) based on character type.  It purposely has defects as an exercise for the reader to remove. :-)

A better algorithm would use a state machine with one or more states for building integers and doubles.  Search the web for "C++ parse double" for more examples.

You could cheat and see what other people have done by searching the web for "c++ RPN calculator" or "c++ prefix calculator".